# I cannot compare my input value with regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate my signup page but I can't...
I'm facing the problem that I cannot compare my input value with regex pattern. The page does not show any message but when I write `alert` then it shows alert when I click the submit button.

**Here is the Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
        var valuee = $("#mail").val();
        var emailRegex = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$'; 

        if (emailRegex.test(valuee)) {
            alert('Great, you entered an E-Mail-address');
        }
        else{
            alert("invalid");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `page does not show any message `:- it will only show message when you do alert or try to add some text somewhere so that it will visible to browser. Can you please post your html and then let us know where you want to show the message exactly and where you face problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate a bit more your problem

Comment: Do you get any error message in the browser console?

Comment: if your alert is working, then it will display your message also .

Comment: `emailRegex` is a string, not a regular expression. If you check the console you'll see an error. Change it to an *actual* regex: `var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/;`

Comment: Now the Small part of problem solve the browser shows invalid even when i write correct format in the input filed...

Comment: Rory McCrossan i did this so Now invalid message is showing even when i write correct format of email address

Comment: Silly question, but just to be sure... You are aware that your regex will only accept uppercase A-Z, right?

Comment: mClarky I also type my email in upper case but again i got invalid message
i type just like that ADNAN@GMAIL.COM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straight-forward problem that your code have is:-

```
var emailRegex = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

Since it's a regular-expression, so you can't treat it as an string.

Change it to:-

```
var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/;
```

***Also its in-correct ,change it like below:-

```
var emailRegex= /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
    var valuee = $("#mail").val();
    var emailRegex = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i; 

    if (emailRegex.test(valuee)) {
        alert('Great, you entered a correct E-Mail-address');
    }
    else{
        alert("invalid");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="mail"/>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="reg-btn" value="Click Me to validate email"/>
```

***Note:-*** there are n number of patterns to check email is valid is not,one of them is:-

```
/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
```

Comment: Now invalid message is showing even when i write correct format of email address

Comment: @AdnanSunny  your regex is not correct to check mail. I have given other-one in my solution example check now.

Comment: @AdnanSunny  i have changed your regex into correct-one. check updated answer now